# Is Charm Monster/Person "harmless" for the purpose of the Insistent Benefactor trait?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw

Do the spells Charm Monster and Charm Person benefit from the [Insistent Benefactor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/insistent-benefactor) trait? More specifically, will it increase the Spell Save DC by 2?

If not, is this because the spells are not explicitly designated as "(harmless)"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it won't apply at all, and your reasoning for why it won't is correct. *Charm person* and company are **certainly not** harmless by the rules, and are in fact offensive spells for the purposes of e.g. *invisibility*.

---

The trait (as you're probably aware) is for casters that routinely buff/heal party members that have class or racial features that require them to attempt a saving throw against all spells, or give them SR they can't lower, or even just regular SR in combat (where taking a standard action to drop all SR for a round is pretty insane) — where ordinary buffing can easily fail when it's most needed. Anything outside that is probably not going to be marked harmless.
It might be possible to use the trait in some deviously offensive way by careful minmaxing, but it won't be nearly this easy.